# Freeing array of struct of array and reusing it cause malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

I have the following program which tries to initialise array `anet` of type `netw` with groups of `M_/N_` equal values, so that the array `s` variable looks like `0 0 0 0 ... 1 1 1 1 ... M_ M_ M_ M_`. At the same time a counter of how many times element `i` of `anet` has been in state `M_` is implemented an array `n_i` inside struct `anet`. `SN_` is the number of simulation i want to repeat, so that for every set of the parameters `M_, N_, T_, L_, C_` which are read from file there will be a for loop executing the initialisation of the array `SN_` times.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
// 
size_t i, j, sm;
int M_, SN_, N_, T_;
double L_, C_;
// 
struct netw {
    int s;
    unsigned long long *n_i;
} *anet;
// 
void freeNet(struct netw *arr);
struct netw *initNet(size_t l);
// 
int main() {
    FILE *f_in;
    f_in = fopen("tmp", "r");
    fscanf(f_in, "%*[^\n]");
    while(fscanf(f_in, "%d %d %d %lf %lf %d", &T_, &N_, &M_, &L_, &C_, &SN_)
        != EOF) {
            printf("%d %d %d %lf %lf %d\n", T_, N_, M_, L_, C_, SN_);
        for (sm = 0; sm < SN_; sm++) {
            anet = initNet(N_);
            freeNet(anet);
        }
    }
    fclose(f_in);
}
void freeNet(struct netw *arr) {
    for (i = 0; i < N_; i++) {
        free(arr[i].n_i);
    }
    free(arr);
}
struct netw *initNet(size_t l) {
    struct netw *arr = calloc(l, sizeof(struct netw));
    int NM_ = (int) l/M_;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i+=NM_) {
        if (i < l - NM_) {
            printf(" i < l - NM_ %zu", i);
            for (j = i; j < i+NM_; j++) {
                printf("\t%zu_1", j);
                arr[j].n_i = calloc(M_, sizeof(unsigned long long));
                arr[j].s = (int) i/NM_;
                printf("\t%d", arr[j].s);
                arr[j].n_i[arr[j].s]++;
                printf("\t%zu_2\n", j);
            }
        } else {
            for (j = i; j < l; j++) {
                printf("\t%zu_1", j);
                arr[j].n_i = calloc(M_, sizeof(unsigned long long));
                arr[j].s = (int) i/NM_;
                printf("\t%d", arr[j].s);
                arr[j].n_i[arr[j].s]++;
                printf("\t%zu_2\n", j);
            }
            printf("i =l - NM_ %zu\n", i);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

values of `M_, SN_, N_, T_, L_, C_` are read form a file `tmp` which looks like

```
# T_    N_      M_      L_      C_      Nsim
500 1000 100 2.00e-01 1.000 10
500 1000 300 2.00e-01 1.000 10
500 1000 500 2.00e-01 1.000 10
500 1000 800 2.00e-01 1.000 10
500 1000 1000 2.00e-01 1.000 10
500 1000 100 2.00e-01 1.100 10
500 1000 300 2.00e-01 1.100 10
500 1000 500 2.00e-01 1.100 10
500 1000 800 2.00e-01 1.100 10
500 1000 1000 2.00e-01 1.100 10
500 1000 100 2.00e-01 1.500 10
500 1000 300 2.00e-01 1.500 10
500 1000 500 2.00e-01 1.500 10
500 1000 800 2.00e-01 1.500 10
500 1000 1000 2.00e-01 1.500 10
```

Now when executing this code it always get stuck at the second row of values with the following error:

```
help_malloc.x(68852,0x10f238dc0) malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x7fa79c264c00: probably modified after being freed.
Corrupt value: 0x1
help_malloc.x(68852,0x10f238dc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
zsh: abort      ./help_malloc.x
```

I tried some basic debugging by putting some printf and I noticed that the first two `sm=0,1` run no problem arises and one get the output

```
 i < l - NM_ 996    996_1   332 996_2
    997_1   332 997_2
    998_1   332 998_2
    999_1   333 999_2
i =l - NM_ 999
```

so that I know that the whole array was successfully initialised, but the third time (is it a case that 3 = NM_ for N_ = 1000 and M_ = 300?) `sm` loop is executed the code stops before `i=999`:

```
i < l - NM_ 957 957_1   319 957_2
    958_1   319 958_2
    959_1   319 959_2
 i < l - NM_ 960    960_1   320 960_2
help_malloc.x(68872,0x119174dc0) malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x7fca85882e00: probably modified after being freed.
Corrupt value: 0x1
help_malloc.x(68872,0x119174dc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
    961_1zsh: abort      ./help_malloc.x
```

What am I doing wrong and why doesn't the code stop before if there is a wrong usage of allocation and freeing of memory?

Answer (score 1):

At glance, my guess is undefined behavior by way of access to unallocated memory.

Running your code, it seems that the problem lies int the calloc call `arr[j].n_i = calloc(M_, sizeof(unsigned long long));`.

In a quick debug using `arr[j].n_i = calloc(M_, sizeof(unsigned long long) + 1);` seems to fixes the issue, but you may need a more comprehensive solution. Likely adjusting your cycles so that there is no out of bounds access.

P.S.: Your code crashes `valgrind`, so congrats on that ;).

Comment: Thanks for your congrats, I was aware of breaking valgrind and very proud of it ;). I tried with a longer list of values and of course `arr[j].n_i = calloc(M_, sizeof(unsigned long long) + 1);` resulted useless. The problem is in calloc of inner array `n_i`, but why? I free all the memory in function `freeNet`. Is it possible that some problems arise due to reusing the same pointer `anet` after freeing it? How comes that a calloc gives such an error?

Comment: @opisthofulax I can't tell, I'm not near the propper tools to really debug it, and looking at it I can't tell, but using the data you provided before the edit and the code fix, it seems to work, take a look https://repl.it/@anastaciu/SunnyAnchoredProcessor

Comment: @anstaciu sorry I forgot to tell I updated the tmp file with more values, not it got stuck later on in the values